# Why is the K silent in 'know' and 'knotty' etc?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, silent-letter

Why don't we read ''k'' here?

> **K**now → /nəʊ/

> **K**notty → /ˈnɒt.i/

> **K**nockout → /ˈnɒk.aʊt/

Comment: Nothing could be easier to find: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_k

Comment: Similarly the leading **G** in gnosis and gnu (except the recursive acronym) and gnarled (which has the synonym *knobbly* ;)

Comment: In German, where these words are borrowed (I believe) you do pronounce the  k, but us English speakers are lazy and don't like saying things like "kuh-night" instead of "knight"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The silent ⟨K⟩ occurs before the letter ⟨N⟩ in most  cases,

e.g. **K**nife , **k**not, **k**nee, **k**now, **k**nowledge, **k**night etc. There are some exceptions which are too few to bother with.

The **⟨kn⟩** combination comes from the Germanic languages where the **K** is still pronounced in some words.

Before the 17th century people in England  also pronounced words like *knee*, and *knife* using the /k/ sound. However, over time, and for whatever reason, the /k/ sound became silent, probably because it was too awkward to pronounce.

There are many advantages to having silent letters in English, and one is that different spellings can help us to differentiate between homophones which are words that are spelt differently, but have the same sound. e.g. *night* and *Knight*.

The silent *e* at the end of words also gives us a clue as to how to pronounce preceding vowels.

Finally, many English spellings are weird because of our history. Our alphabet has a limited number of letters and therefore couldn't accommodate the influx of new sounds and words brought in by invaders over the centuries.

---

<sup>⟨Angled brackets⟩ represent orthography (spelling) while /slashes/ represent sounds</sup>

Comment: I've made an edit to your answer, please roll-back if it doesn't strike your fancy. :)